# K8s minikube can't access hosted http (external) service

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

### Environment

- Windows 10 OS
- WSL2 ( minikube is using Linux containers )
- minikube v1.25.2
- kubectl v1.23.0

### Use-case

- pod 1 - mongodb
- pod 2 - mongo express
- Internal service for accessing mongodb
- External service (LoadBalancer) for accessing mongo express from a browser

### Problem at hand

Running the following opens a browser on service EndPoint but the mongo express page doesn't load giving "**This site can’t be reached**"

```
minikube.exe service mongo-express-service
```

### YAML Files

---

### mongo-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb-deployment
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: mongo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        env:
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-username
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key:  mongo-root-password
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongodb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

### mongoexpress-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-express
  labels:
    app: mongo-express
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo-express
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo-express
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongo-express
        image: mongo-express
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8081
        env:
          - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mongodb-secret
                key: mongo-root-username
          - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mongodb-secret
                key:  mongo-root-password
          - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: mongodb-configmap
                key: database_url
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-express-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo-express
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
      nodePort: 30000
```

### mongo-configmap.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mongodb-configmap
data:
  database_url: mongodb-service
```

### mongo-secret.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mongodb-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  mongo-root-username: cm9vdA==
  mongo-root-password: ZXhhbXBsZQ==
```

### .\kubectl.exe get all -o wide

```
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE   IP           NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/mongo-express-68c4748bd6-5qnnh        1/1     Running   2 (16h ago)   20h   172.17.0.3   minikube   <none>           <none>
pod/mongodb-deployment-7bb6c6c4c7-w2bdx   1/1     Running   1 (16h ago)   22h   172.17.0.4   minikube   <none>           <none>

NAME                            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE   SELECTOR
service/kubernetes              ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          8d    <none>
service/mongo-express-service   LoadBalancer   10.108.182.35    <pending>     8081:30000/TCP   20h   app=mongo-express
service/mongodb-service         ClusterIP      10.107.207.139   <none>        27017/TCP        21h   app=mongodb

NAME                                 READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE   CONTAINERS      IMAGES          SELECTOR
deployment.apps/mongo-express        1/1     1            1           20h   mongo-express   mongo-express   app=mongo-express
deployment.apps/mongodb-deployment   1/1     1            1           22h   mongodb         mongo           app=mongodb

NAME                                            DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE   CONTAINERS      IMAGES          SELECTOR
replicaset.apps/mongo-express-68c4748bd6        1         1         1       20h   mongo-express   mongo-express   app=mongo-express,pod-template-hash=68c4748bd6
replicaset.apps/mongo-express-6f76745c84        0         0         0       20h   mongo-express   mongo-express   app=mongo-express,pod-template-hash=6f76745c84
replicaset.apps/mongodb-deployment-7bb6c6c4c7   1         1         1       22h   mongodb         mongo           app=mongodb,pod-template-hash=7bb6c6c4c7
```

**While executing *minikube.exe service mongo-express-service* the browser opens on *http://192.168.49.2:30000/* and returns "*This site can’t be reached 192.168.49.2 took too long to respond.*", same happen if I use the loopback IP, what am I doing wrong ?**

Comment: ["A LoadBalancer service is the standard way to expose a service to the internet](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#loadbalancer-access) As I understand, you want to access the service from the browser on a host machine, am I right? In that case you need to use Nodeport type service instead LoadBalancer. And then run `minikube service --url mongo-express-service` to fetching the minikube IP and a service’s NodePort.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewSkorkin for your response, but, using NodePort didn;t seem to solve the problem.. the IP allocated for the service is not the loopback IP and is inaccessible...

service/mongo-express-service   NodePort    10.108.182.35    <none>        8081:30000/TCP   3d23h

Comment: Did you try `minikube service --url mongo-express-service` command? You will get an IP to access the service.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it appears that I had to use *minikube tunnel* to enable access to the service, strangely, the mongo express service was accessible on port 8081 rather than 30000... I guess this is because it is bring access by the tunnel and not directly

```
kubectl get svc
NAME                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes              ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          8d
mongo-express-service   LoadBalancer   10.108.182.35    127.0.0.1     8081:30000/TCP   22h
mongodb-service         ClusterIP      10.107.207.139   <none>        27017/TCP        23h
```